# Hide when no longer hovering using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want the div `#reloadWarningBackground` to show ONLY when hovering over the button `#reloadButton`.

Here is my code:

```
$('#reloadButton').mouseover(function() {
    $('#reloadWarningBackground').show();
});
```

Comment: Can you add respective HTML too

Answer (score 2):

Use `mouseout` like following.

```
$('#reloadButton').mouseover(function() {
    $('#reloadWarningBackground').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('#reloadWarningBackground').hide();
})
```

**UPDATE**

It is better to use `mouseenter` since `mouseover` will be executed repeatedly.

```
$('#reloadButton').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#reloadWarningBackground').show();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('#reloadWarningBackground').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best way to address this problem is using toggle().

//html

```
<button id="reloadButton">
    Hover me
</button>
<div id="reloadWarningBackground" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        Hello this is me
    </p>
</div>
```

//Javascript

```
$('#reloadButton').hover(function() {
    $('#reloadWarningBackground').toggle();
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1L5nzz3/)